# Using a class or an interface as VALUE when declaring a Map

Tags: java, class, interface

I'm cleaning a code and I've found something that made me doubt.

I have this:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<?>> credentials = (LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<?>>) [...]
```

Is this correct? Should I refactor as:

```
Map<String, List<?>> credentials = (LinkedHashMap<String, List<?>>) [...]
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Sergio

Comment: it hardly depends on what are you planning to do latter with the values of that map....

Comment: If you want reuse it as a generic one in multiple context with different 'List` implementation then 'List' interface is the best option, and for single scope use you can use `ArrayList` which makes your code more implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

The List is the base interface for all list types, and the ArrayList and LinkedList classes are two common List's implementations. You can keep as "ArrayList", which is specific implementation of List Interface

```
Map<String, ArrayList<?>> credentials = (LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<?>>) [...]
```